# Applying two attributes colors and font size to the same selector

Tags: html, css

I want to apply two different colours and font-sizes to a text logo.

Imagine the logo as : "Cairo Washers".

I would like to make "Cairo" in green text and I would like to make "Washers" in black text in a smaller font size and starting from the top right side of " Cairo ". The same way you'd write an exponent value to a number in calculus.

How may achieve that?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow @Haid. For us to be able to help you please include code (HTML and CSS) showing what you have attempted so far.

Comment: If it is your logo, it is better to draw it and use as an image. That way you will ensure it looks the same in every browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We already have a tag that does that: `<sup>`

Per [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/sup)

> The HTML Superscript Element (`<sup>`) defines a span of text that should be displayed, for typographic reasons, higher, and often smaller, than the main span of text.

```css
span {
  font-size: 72px;
  color: green;
}
sup {
  vertical-align: super;
  font-size: 32px;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<span>Cairo<sup>Washers</sup></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way how you can achive in css :

https://jsfiddle.net/Alteyss/e9aj3qgs/

```
div {
    display: inline-block;
}
#a {
    color: red;
    font-size : 30pt;
}
#b {
    color: black;
    font-size : 10pt;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

I advice you to create an image instead, it's better in a website...

Comment: Thank you a lot. Although I won't use this snippet of code for the text logo. It gave me an idea for something else.
As for the image, our logo uses black and green helevetica text. I thought it would be unnecessary to clog my content folder with a huge png picture.

Answer (score -1):

```
p{
color:green;
}
p span{
color:black;
}

<p>Cairo <span>Washers</span></p>
```